# enable/disable input with a select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I know that this question has already been done
before, but, I have had problems to make it work, to test the script
only in a new html works, but when I integrate it to my platform does
not respond, but other script does. The select gets the data of a
query in mysql, and when selecting the other option the input should
be enabled, and in any other option disable.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#mat').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "Otro") {
   $('#otro_mat').prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
   $('#otro_mat').prop("disabled", true);
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<select class="form-control" name="mat" id="mat">
 <?php
  switch ($row["mat"]){
   case "Concreto":
 ?>
    <option value="#">Selecciona Una Opción</option>
 <option selected value="Concreto">Concreto</option>
 <option value="Acero">Acero</option>
 <option value="Madera">Madera</option>
 <option value="Mixto">Mixto</option>
 <option value="Mamposteria">Mamposteria</option>
 <option value="Otro">Otro</option>
 <?php
 break;
 case "Acero":
 ?>
 <option value="#">Selecciona Una Opción</option>
 <option value="Concreto">Concreto</option>
 <option selected value="Acero">Acero</option>
 <option value="Madera">Madera</option>
 <option value="Mixto">Mixto</option>
 <option value="Mamposteria">Mamposteria</option>
 <option value="Otro">Otro</option>
 <?php
 break;
 case "Madera":
 ?>
 <option value="#">Selecciona Una Opción</option>
 <option value="Concreto">Concreto</option>
 <option value="Acero">Acero</option>
 <option selected value="Madera">Madera</option>
 <option value="Mixto">Mixto</option>
 <option value="Mamposteria">Mamposteria</option>
 <option value="Otro">Otro</option>
 <?php
 break;
 case "Mixto":
 ?>
 <option value="#">Selecciona Una Opción</option>
 <option value="Concreto">Concreto</option>
 <option value="Acero">Acero</option>
 <option value="Madera">Madera</option>
 <option selected value="Mixto">Mixto</option>
 <option value="Mamposteria">Mamposteria</option>
 <option value="Otro">Otro</option>
 <?php
 break;
 case "Mamposteria":
 ?>
 <option value="#">Selecciona Una Opción</option>
 <option value="Concreto">Concreto</option>
 <option value="Acero">Acero</option>
 <option value="Madera">Madera</option>
 <option value="Mixto">Mixto</option>
 <option selected value="Mamposteria">Mamposteria</option>
 <option value="Otro">Otro</option>
 <?php
 break;
 case "Otro":
 ?>
 <option value="#">Selecciona Una Opción</option>
 <option value="Concreto">Concreto</option>
 <option value="Acero">Acero</option>
 <option value="Madera">Madera</option>
 <option value="Mixto">Mixto</option>
 <option value="Mamposteria">Mamposteria</option>
 <option selected value="Otro">Otro</option>
 <?php
 break;
 }
 ?>
</select><br>

<input type="text" name="mat_otro" id="otro_mat" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['mat_otro'];?>">
```

Comment: You seem to be saying that the JS shown works in isolation but doesn't work when integrated with other code, but you haven't shown any other code so I'm not sure how we can help. Have you included jquery.js on the page? And do you get any error messages in the browser's console? As an aside, if you'd like shorter code you can replace the if/else with `$('#otro_mat').prop("disabled", this.value != "Otro");`.

Comment: Just  a comment, you should not duplicated so much when you are just trying to determine what is selected from the options. You should have one set of options only. You can do something like `<option value="Concreto"<?php if($row["mat"] == 'Concreto') echo ' selected' ?>>Concreto</option>` and so on.

Comment: Thanks Rasclatt, I miss that but edit now.

Comment: nnnnnn I dont copy all the code beacuse only change in the content of the page, I mean, is the same but without the another options of the form when I try it in a new HTML. The jquery.js is included, i have another scripts an they works but this "#$%&/( doesn't. And the console dont show me anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `otro_mat` id is assigned to only one input field.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#otro_mat').attr('disabled','disabled');        

    $('select[name="mat"]').on('change',function(){
       var  Otro = $(this).val();
       if(Otro == "Otro"){           
           $('#otro_mat').removeAttr('disabled');          
       }else{
           $('#otro_mat').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
       }  

  });
});
</script>
```

See this Live [jsfiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ankit29/3chbonhj/1/)

Comment: yes, I try it, but isnt works, I dont understeand, why works in a new html, but in my form didnt

Comment: ok thats new, in the console show me "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" but is with the code you suggested ankit shuthar

Comment: Add JQuery library before your script so that $ can be identified. @RicardoAlvarez

Comment: I do it before check your answer, and it works, I think when I changing the script should have put my code above the library...

Comment: Thanks to all guys!

Comment: Por favor,  if your problem is solved then you can accept my answer @RicardoAlvarez

Comment: (Muchas) Gracias @RicardoAlvarez